# Plastic in Roman Concrete?

Tags: alternate-history, construction, materials

[Word on the street is that using recycled plastic to make roads can help reduce carbon emissions, improve road quality by making it longer-lasting and less susceptible to potholing.](https://futurism.com/an-engineer-has-found-a-way-to-create-plastic-roads/)

This revolutionary idea has me thinking.  Plastic has been used for thousands of years--it's just that the modern definition and composition of "plastic" did not start until 1907.  A good example of "plastic" is rubber used from a rubber tree.  It was used by the Mesoamerican tribes as far away as the third millennium BCE.

The problem is that natural rubber trees are indigenous to the jungles of Latin America, and the rubber tree plantations used in India and China were cultivated from seeds taken by British scientists and financiers.

Let us pretend, then, that in an alternate Earth, a species of wild rubber is common in the Mediterranean coastlines of southern Europe and had been used by the Romans for cultivation for their sap.  This would be the sort of natural plastic to be used for concrete construction, to make the structure last longer against the elements than subsequent "Portland reinforced" concrete.  In OTL, volcanic ash already added resistance to Roman concrete, but in this alternate Earth, could using rubber, one of the most natural of plastics, have the same effect?

Comment: Plastic makes a terrible road surface. It would not/will not be used as a road surface.

Comment: While I agree with @JoeKissling, normal plastics, as they are right now, wouldn't make a good road surface, that's not the only way they can be used.  We do need a bit more information as to why and what would be used

Comment: Is the plastic like substance going to be used to add structure, or adhesion, or any of a number of other things we use cement for.  Is it going to be biodegradable?  If moisture and local bacteria will break it sown over a few years, it may not be great

Comment: Natural rubber is not very good at resisting "against the elements"; it is very much worse than concrete. At least concrete is not damaged by light.

Comment: Also, notice that the proposals to change how we make roads come from people that aren't civil engineers. And while we make fun of them because a major part of their job is to mix water and dirt to make mud, they are very good at what they do and if there really was a better way they would suggest it.

Comment: Didn't you even READ the link?

Comment: Also...https://thinkprogress.org/netherlands-company-introduces-plastic-roads-that-are-more-durable-climate-friendly-than-asphalt-ecb7c2a11a50  http://www.motortrend.com/news/u-k-testing-roads-made-recycled-plastics/  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHWYoDKYnQo  http://mashable.com/2017/02/24/recycled-plastic-roads-volkerwessels/#Xq58kQHOIsqx  http://www.thedrive.com/news/9748/roads-made-of-recycled-plastic-are-being-tested-in-britain

Comment: @JohnWDailey Recycled plastic is not suitable for UV exposure, it will degrade under the sunlight. During the heat of the day, it will expand and become malleable and deform under the weight of cars. All the pictures/videos show a road that is hopelessly unsuitable for traffic.

Comment: The wording still looks like someone who has not read the links.

Comment: @JohnWDailey I did read the links.

Comment: So why doubt it?

Comment: @JohnWDailey Because these ideas are not well thought out. The biggest issue is that recycled plastics do not tolerate UV exposure, they will degrade in the sun. There is no mention at all in mitigating that. Also the listed opening temp is 170 F which is not high enough to be used for roads because it will deform in the summer heat. I have no doubt the strength of the material, but its environmental hardiness I see lacking.

Answer (score 9):

Um...no.

If you look at the link you opened with, you'll notice that the proposal is to use plastic in place of bitumen (asphalt, tar...it has various names) in tarmac roads, not concrete ones.

Tarmac is literally just gravel mixed with a binder - currently we use bitumen for this purpose, also called asphalt or tar. Its role is to keep the gravel from shifting around as vehicles move over it, while the gravel prevents the bitumen from being worn away. In the proposal above, the idea is to replace bitumen with recycled plastic.

Concrete is a totally different thing. Concrete consists of gravel, sand, water, and most critically, cement. The cement binds with the other ingredients and undergoes a chemical reaction that causes the whole matrix to become effectively solid stone. It's that chemical process that gives concrete its strength - and rubber has none of the necessary properties to replace it.

Comment: Also, the the asphalt in old roads *is* recycled: they scrape up the old road material, haul it away, heat it up, mix it up, add some more asphalt and aggregate, then lay it down on the next road that needs to be repaved.

Answer (score 5):

No, Roman concrete and asphalt are not the same thing.

No, rubber is not a suitable replacement for bitumen in asphalt roads.

#### However...

The Romans were famous for building roads, and asphalt concrete is great for roads. Asphalt is *also* useful for coating concrete structures to provide a degree of waterproofing (asphalt shingles being probably the most popular roofing material--in the USA, at least).

So the question becomes, could the Romans utilize asphalt to create roads and as a water-proofing pitch? And, if so, what role could rubber play?

We know the Romans had access to bitumen (the pitch/binding agent in asphalt concrete). The Egyptians used bitumen as a mummifying agent which they harvested from the Dead Sea. The Romans' name for the Dead Sea? Palus Asphaltites (Asphalt Lake).

#### Now we're getting somewhere...

So, the Romans had access to bitumen/asphalt and undoubtedly knew of its water-proofing properties. The problem is, it's hard to acquire in the kinds of significant quantities you'd need to build a few thousand miles of roads or roof a few thousand buildings without modern oil-drilling equipment. It wasn't in widespread use as a ship caulking agent until the 1400s for this very reason. What to do?

#### Enter rubber

Rubber, on its own, does not provide a suitable pitch-like binding agent for asphalt concrete. However, [rubber has been mixed into asphalt concrete for 170 years](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0950061813008477). This increases the durability/longevity of the road and provides a partial replacement for bitumen. So, while you can't *entirely* get rid of your dependence on bitumen, you *can* significantly reduce your dependence on it by substituting rubber for some of it, *and also* it provides a longer-lasting material.

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons Roman concrete structures have lasted so long, in particular those actually *in* water was the Romans used volcanic ash in their concrete formula.

While naturally occurring wild rubber plants in AE (alt-earth) would be interest and somewhat difficult to derive a reason for volcanoes are quite ready to take their place.

Make roads with Roman concrete, use the ash Luke.

Comment: And what is the problem with a volcanic solution?

Comment: In my alternate Earth, volcanoes are less accessible in the Trojan Empire than in the Roman Empire.  http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Plate-Tectonics-Great-Lakes-Earth-668631992

Comment: Which wasn't in the question. Why didn't you just say, "I am using rubber" as that is the answer you had decided on. Rubber will not work. But it's a story so whatever.

Comment: It didn't seem relevant.  Also, a story still needs realism, otherwise it's not believable.

Comment: @JohnWDailey - Okay, so using rubber plants that are world wide (and not believable) is realistic and *will not work* as road materials is **more believable** than using volcanic ash (which was actually used by our Romans). And Earth is still ringed with volcanoes so that's not realistic either. **Right**.

Comment: The issue is that ash is less available in this alternate Earth.

Answer (score -2):

The [plastic roadways idea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sj_FZduqblo)<sup>※</sup> is pure bunk, on **every issue**.  The ancients new that asphalt was an amazing hi-tech material for roadmaking, and would quickly determine that resin composites are not.

Adding fibers *to* concrete may be helpful, but has issues in getting it to work right.  So you don’t need rubber or “plastic” technology for that, but can use horsehair etc.  For cases where that *works*, see the [caulk used in shipbuilding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caulking#Wooden_shipbuilding) — made using fiber recycled from old rope.  This is used to make a flexible seal, not a hard-wearing surface.

The ancients did not need rubber to understand how to use composites.  Other materials were available, and did indeed find suitable uses. Road surface is not one of them.

---

※ I contributed significantly to the funding of this “busted” video.

Comment: If you follow the link, you'll see it's a different use of plastic in roadways, not the one busted by Thunderf00t. It's a proposal to replace the bitumen in roads with recycled plastic, not to make the entire road out of plastic sections.

Comment: I think that is covered in the video.  It’s been a while since I went over it, but bitumen rings a bell.

Comment: OP's link uses recycled plastic as a replacement for asphalt/bitumen in the concrete, _not_ as a purely plastic road (as in your link). As a road surface, pure plastic isn't a good idea. As a binding pitch for concrete, it's a less ridiculous idea.

Comment: @Azuaron Less ridiculous = ridiculous

Comment: Yes, it is - I rewatched the video before I made my answer. Bitumen is mentioned because it's what roads are currently made of.

Comment: It's a shame though that Thunderf00t seems to have lost it

Comment: "*but has issues in getting it to work right*" **asbestos** has long, strong fibers and is an *excellent* reinforcement of concrete.  For many decades, it was used to strengthen concrete roof and siding shingles and (outdoor) wallboard.

Comment: @RonJohn Asbestos is great for many things: fireproofing, reenforcing, cancer, filters, and much more!

Comment: @JoeKissling filters?

Comment: @RonJohn yeah, I find it hard to believe too

Comment: I need a more professional source of info.

Comment: @JohnWDailey LOL, there's a reason I don't read click-bait sites like that.